# Attach Comments to Specific Objects in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

It it possible to attach comments to specific text or objects in PowerPoint 2016? The default behavior seems to insert comment icons at a certain position in the document, but they retain no link to, say, a specific shape or text string. I would like to insert comments that will remain associated with what they are commenting on, even as elements in the document are moved around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to attach the usual PowerPoint comments to specific shapes.

There are a couple ways you can attach comment text to a specific shape but none of them makes it obvious to the user that the shape has comment text.

For example, you can rightclick the shape, choose Format and add the comment to the ALT text for the shape (so long as you don't need to use ALT text to make the presentation accessible to eg. screenreader users).

It'd also be possible to draw another shape, type the comment text into it, then group it with the shape it applies to.

VBA (or other programming languages) will allow you to add multiple "tags" to any shape or slide in the presentation, but again, the text isn't visible to the user unless you make it so using more VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your response! (But bad news for my intended application: annotating a process flowchart with threaded comments by different reviewers.) I may be able to use the ALT text to accomplish some of what I aim to do.

Comment: Update: I am not yet sure of this, but it seems as if Microsoft Visio may have the functionality that I want.

Comment: It's been quite a while since I last used Visio but I'm betting you're correct.